# How can i change color in my sheet if browser profile url checkpoint with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change color text in my Sheet in Excel if anyprofile browser checkpoint but it alway error when i use oExec in my if:

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
        Dim chromePro As String
        Dim wshell As Object
        Dim oExec As Object 
    chromePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --profile-directory=""Profile "
    myUrl = "https://www.facebook.com"

    Dim LastRow As Long, intRow As Long
    With Worksheets("Data")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For intRow = 1 To LastRow
        myPr = Range("A" & intRow).Value
        chromePro = (chromePath & "" & myPr & """ " & myUrl)
        Set wshell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
        Set oExec = wshell.exec(chromePro)
        cUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/checkpoint/"
        nchromePro = (chromePath & "" & myPr & """ " & cUrl)
        ***'This block i want to record checkpoint but it error when i use oExec in if***
        If oExec = nchromePro Then
            .Range("A" & intRow).Font.Color = vbRed
        Else
            .Range("A" & intRow).Font.Color = vbBlack
        End If
    Next intRow
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I suggest you start with placing `Option Explicit` at the top of your code module and then eliminate the myriad of errors that will show up. Then consider that `If oExec = nchromePro` compares two objects, the type of neither of which is declared, neither of which necessarily exists at that point, and that objects can't be compared with each other using this syntax. Use `If oExec Is nchromePro` instead if both objects do exist and are of comparable type.

Comment: Hi @Variatus, It's always show **Compile Error: Type mismatch** please help me brother

Comment: It's probably because `oExec` and `nchromePro` aren't comparable objects or one of them didn't get created. It'\s complicated. Your best chance is to go back to where you got the code from. Else, you might ask another question here like, "How can I determine if my code creates the `oExec` and `nchromePro` objects successfully? Don't post the same code as in this thread again. Post the version you will have after fixing the declarations with the help of *Option Explicit*.